# Convert integer data type to time

Tags: sql, sql-server, type-conversion

My table lists the date and time fields as integer data types. I need to convert them to normal date formats. I have the date field done. How can I convert the time field with SQL?

| AppointmentDate | AppointmentTime | NewDate | NewTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20230329 | 830 | 3/29/2023 | 8:30 AM |
| 20230516 | 1330 | 5/16/2023 | 1:30 PM |
| 20230403 | 1500 | 4/3/2023 | 3:00 PM |
| 20230329 | 1020 | 3/29/2023 | 10:20 AM |

Comment: Note that tables have _columns_, not fields. (But a date has a year _field_, a month _field_ etc.)

Comment: @jarlh In the database world, columns = fields & rows = records = tuples. The names have been interchangeable my entire career.

Comment: _The terms column, field, and attribute refer to structural components of tables, row types, and structured types, respectively, in analogous fashion. As the structure of a table consists of one or more columns, so does the structure of a row type consist of one or more fields and that of a structured type one or more attributes._ ANSI/ISO SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

```
TimeFromParts(AppointmentTime/100, AppointmentTime%100, 0, 0, 0)
```

> [TimeFromParts() Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/timefromparts-transact-sql)

Lots of people will use a string-based solution instead, because that's the obvious answer. However, this is a case where the obvious answer is definitely **not** your best choice. Thanks to cultural/internationalization issues, string-based solutions will pretty much always be slower and more error-prone. If this is how you handled the date conversion, you might also want to revise the Date code to use the equivalent [`DateFromParts()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql) method:

```
DateFromParts(AppointmentDate / 10000, AppointmentDate / 100 % 100, AppointmentDate % 100)
```

If it were me, I'd also [combine Date and Time into the same column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datetimefromparts-transact-sql):

```
DateTimeFromParts(AppointmentDate / 10000, AppointmentDate / 100 % 100, AppointmentDate % 100, AppointmentTime / 100, AppointmentTime % 100, 0, 0)
```

Comment: "Thanks to cultural/internationalization issues, string-based solutions will pretty much always be slower" that's not the only reason they're slower, they're slower because more calculations even if you had a fixed format. But good answer anyway

Comment: @Charlieface Definitely. But I've found the cultural issues are the reason people will actually listen to in order to prompt a lasting change in behavior.

Answer (score -1):

I usually do a double cast for int => varchar => date:

```sql
SELECT CAST(CAST(20230329 AS VARCHAR(8)) AS DATETIME)
```

For time, it's something like:

```sql
SELECT CAST(STUFF(RIGHT('0' + CAST(830 AS VARCHAR(4)), 4), 3, 0, ':') AS TIME)
```

You pad out the time to simplify the insert of ':' and then cast to time.

To combine into datetime:

```sql
SELECT CAST(CAST(20230329 AS VARCHAR(8)) + ' ' + STUFF(RIGHT('0' + CAST(830 AS VARCHAR(4)), 4), 3, 0, ':') AS DATETIME)
```